# Check if a specific class exist(button)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Got a problem with my function I have no idea how to make it work. Without if it works but spams in console. This function check if a multiple div `class('open button')` exist and do the code

```
(function() {
    function openbutton() {
        var button = setInterval(function() {
            if (getEBCN('open button').length > 0) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.getElementsByClassName("open button")[0].click();
                }, 1000);

                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.getElementsByClassName("button 2")[0].click();
                }, 1500);

                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.getElementsByClassName("button close")[0].click();
                }, 18000);
            }
            else {
                clearInterval(button);
            }
        }, 16000);
    }
})();
```

Comment: `getEBCN is not defined`, if you know what I mean

Comment: I'm guessing `getEBCN(class)` stands for `getElementByClassName(class)`

Comment: You have a problem? What problem?

Comment: what error is shown in console,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply do

```
const existFlag = document.getElementsByClassName('someClassName').length > 0;
```

```js
setInterval(function(){
  const existFlag = document.getElementsByClassName('sampleClass').length > 0;
  console.log(existFlag)
}, 3000);
```

Comment: that, in an interval, will throw an error. If you're providing an answer, why not shape it to fit the OP's requirement?

Comment: I don't see `const` in your interval :)

Comment: @Adelin Updated, I don't why you think it doesn't work in setInterval...

Comment: Because you can't overwrite a `const` variable, which `setInterval` might do, depending on where you use it. My point is that dropping a line of code like that is not a good answer.

Comment: @Adelin You are partially right. It is clear that I can't overwrite const variable in the same scope. But having a function inside the setInterval make a different scope every time, so there is no overwriting issue.

Answer (score 0):

`getEBCN` is not a method in JavaScript (unless you have defined it). You need to change

`getEBCN('open button').length > 0`

to

`document.getElementsByClassName('open button').length > 0`

Comment: @Adelin Oops, forgot the `document`. Thanks, I’ve edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well that works @user3003238. This do rly what i wanted.

```
(function() {
        setInterval(function(){
            const existFlag = document.getElementsByClassName('open button').length > 0;
            console.log(existFlag);
            if (existFlag == true)
            {
                    setTimeout(function() {document.getElementsByClassName("open button")[0].click();}, 1000);
                    setTimeout(function() {document.getElementsByClassName("button 2")[0].click();}, 1500);
                    setTimeout(function() {document.getElementsByClassName("button close")[0].click();}, 18000);
            }
            else
            {
                clearInterval();
            }
        }, 20000);
})();
```